# Asterisk broadcast mechanism

Tags: asterisk, voip

I want to ask how the mechanism when broadcast communication occurs (many endpoints) where each endpoint enters the bridge through the ARI originate (outgoing call) function.
Suppose there are 3 participants in a communication bridge. When one endpoint is talking, how does the mechanism occur? Does the endpoint make 2 packets with the same payload, then sent separately by the endpoint or only send one packet, then the asterisk duplicates the packet as much as n endpoint then sends it to each endpoint registered on the bridge?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can check app_conference.c code if you want.

Asterisk make independend packet for each party. How that packet created will depend on confbridge settings.

There is experimental res_rtp_multicast.c, but it not used in most scenarios.